# Python - Replacing parts of a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have to create guess lines where the user guesses subwords of a larger word formatted like this:

```
>>> create_guess_line(2, 8) 
’Guess 2 | - | * | * | * | - | - | - | - |’
```

where the sub-guesses needed to be guessed are denoted by asterisks and are defined by the given tuple:

```
GUESS_INDEX_TUPLE = (
    ((0,1),(2,4),(2,4),(3,5),(2,5),(0,5)),                  # word length 6
    ((0,1),(1,2),(4,6),(2,5),(3,6),(2,6),(0,6)),            # word length 7
    ((0,1),(1,3),(4,7),(3,5),(3,6),(5,7),(2,7),(0,7)),          # word length 8
    ((0,1),(1,3),(4,7),(3,5),(3,6),(5,7),(3,7),(2,8),(0,8))     # word length 9
)
```

How do i put the asterisks in the right places? here is my attempt so far:

```
def create_guess_line(guess_no, word_length):
    WALL_VERTICAL = ' | '
    WALL_HORIZONTAL = ' - '
    blanks = (WALL_VERTICAL + WALL_HORIZONTAL) * word_length + WALL_VERTICAL
    subguess = blanks.replace(WALL_HORIZONTAL, ' * ')
    index1 = GUESS_INDEX_TUPLE[word_length - 6][guess_no -1][0]
    index2 = GUESS_INDEX_TUPLE[word_length - 6][guess_no -1][1]
    blanks = blanks[0:index1] + subguess + blanks[index2+1:word_length]
    print ('Guess ' + str(guess_no) + blanks)
```

I'm getting the asterisks but too many. I'm assuming it is messing up due to multiplying blanks by the word length, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the word length in a different way.

Comment: can you post the desired result?

Comment: @AnnZen the desired result is pictured in the first bit of code create_guess_line(guess_no, word_length) where the guess number is 2 and the word length is 8. The asterisks are placed in relation to CREATE_GUESS_TUPLE[2][1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is that this line creates a string that's too long:

```
blanks = (WALL_VERTICAL + WALL_HORIZONTAL) * word_length + WALL_VERTICAL
```

Here `word_length` is 8, but you only want 3 asterisks.

A cleaner approach is to make an array of `-` or `*` characters, and then join them. This will allow you to do a slice assignment like:

```
blanks[index1: index2] = ['*'] * (index2 - index1)
```

If you are always going to be slicing with the second number in the tuple, you might consider adding one to it in the data itself (I've done that in the code here). In this example I replaced you list of tuples with a dict just to make the example easier to understand

```
GUESS_INDEX_TUPLE = {
   6: ((0,1),(2,4),(2,4),(3,5),(2,5),(0,5)),                  # word length 6
   7: ((0,1),(1,2),(4,6),(2,5),(3,6),(2,6),(0,6)),            # word length 7
   8: ((0,1),(1,3),(4,7),(3,5),(3,6),(5,7),(2,7),(0,7)),      # word length 8
   9: ((0,1),(1,3),(4,7),(3,5),(3,6),(5,7),(3,7),(2,8),(0,8)) # word length 9
}

def create_guess_line(guess_no, word_length):
    WALL_VERTICAL = ' | '
    WALL_HORIZONTAL = ' - '

    blanks = [WALL_HORIZONTAL] * word_length
    
    index1, index2 = GUESS_INDEX_TUPLE[word_length][guess_no - 1]
    index2 += 1
    
    blanks[index1: index2] = ['*'] * (index2 - index1)
    print (f'Guess {guess_no}'
           f'{WALL_VERTICAL}'
           f'{WALL_VERTICAL.join(blanks)}'
           f'{WALL_VERTICAL}'
    )

create_guess_line(2, 8)
# Guess 2 |  -  | * | * | * |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |
```